# Symfony : what's the accessor of getCulture() in a form class?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, widget

I would like to replace that :

```
$p = new sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCountry(array('culture' => 'en'));
```

by

```
$p = new sfWidgetFormI18nChoiceCountry(array('culture' => getCulture()));
```

but i'm missing one accessor to use getCulture and i can't remember what.

**What is the acessor to use getCulture on the form class ? What's your technique to remember the acessors ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$culture = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture();
```

But the preferred Symfony way is to "inject" the culture into the form class from your action:

```
$this->form = new SomethingForm(array(), array('culture' => $culture)); // Inject it this way in your action

$culture = $this->getOption('culture'); // Get it like this in your form class
```